# I minted an NFT using an interface I created but the media (image) is not showing up on opensea

Tags: nft, opensea, meta-data

I minted an NFT. This is the metadata - https://bafybeictwd4bz4aof7gfl7mkdmzdqfgdpwijuvvrun6ytr7sqvgrd6p4oi.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/

But the image is not showing up on opensea - https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x5d10fd561a8ff2fb1ad67dc209ffb49838ebd63b/7.

Why is this so?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Reading through [OpenSea Metadata standards](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards), you'll find that your json data field with the image link needs to be called "image" instead of "imageCID".